# Pass ID of a form like in argument to function click()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 24 buttons like this:

```
`<form id="start_0" class="KEY_MENU">
            <button class="btnn">1</button>

            </form>
            <form id="start" class="KEY_OK">
            <button class="btnn">2</button>

            </form>`
```

I want to call them with jquery like this:

```
                $('#arg').click(remote)
```

how can i pass ID start_0 or start like in argument to function click
thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you are looking to **trigger** click or **detect** click, below is detecting click and getting the ID of its parent form.

```
$(document).on("click",".btnn",function(){
     id = $(this).parent("form").attr("id");
});
```